# Ubuntu crashing after 18.04 update

Tags: crash

I did the suggested update today.  After rebooting my computer, it has crashed twice after just a few minutes of running.  Any ideas?

$ ls -al /var/crash
total 129052
drwxrwxrwt  2 root   root       4096 Nov 28 07:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root   root       4096 Sep  8 14:48 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          0 Nov 28 07:45 .lock
-rw-r-----  1 tharpa tharpa   292617 Nov 27 22:15 _usr_bin_desktopnova-daemon.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 tharpa tharpa  3985870 Nov 27 22:36 _usr_bin_lxqt-session.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 tharpa tharpa  4389788 Nov 22 08:43 _usr_bin_pcmanfm-qt.1000.crash
----------  1 tharpa tharpa 89956352 Nov 27 19:16 _usr_lib_chromium-browser_chromium-browser.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 tharpa tharpa 33167682 Nov 24 09:46 _usr_lib_libreoffice_program_soffice.bin.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root   root     241994 Nov 27 23:02 _usr_sbin_aptd.0.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root          0 Nov 27 23:02 _usr_sbin_aptd.0.upload
-rw-r-----  1 tharpa tharpa    92476 Nov 27 19:26 _usr_share_cinnamon-screensaver_cinnamon-screensaver-main.py.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 tharpa tharpa        0 Nov 22 13:27 _usr_share_cinnamon-screensaver_cinnamon-screensaver-main.py.1000.upload

@heynnema

Just crashed again.

Not sure how to read the .crash files.  I guess they're binary files, because they sure nothing when opened in a text editor.

Comment: My upgrade to 18.04 had no errors, and the resulting system was stable and ran fast. How is your system different from mine?

Comment: @user535733 lol  You thought I was saying that no one in the world was running it successfully?  Tell me how yours is and I'll tell you how mine is different.  Don't leave out any details!

Comment: No, I was subtly telling you that the question is too broad. Sorry that didn't come across. There could be many realistically-possible causes, and  whole archipelago of weird or corner-case causes. Are you asking for troubleshooting advice? Are you really asking for a vast list of largely-irrelevant 'ideas' and opinions? Or are you asking for something else?

Comment: Edit your question with any more details that you can supply, and the `terminal` output of `ls -al /var/crash`. Report back to @heynnema